# Should I control for population in my regression?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, feature-selection, econometrics, fixed-effects-model

I am conducting a fixed effects regression on panel data for different counties in the UK.

My variables have all been engineered to be rates per 1000 people (e.g. unemployment per 1000 people).

I was wondering if when conducting the regression, it would be appropriate to use the population as one of the control variable in the regression equation.

As the population was used to find the "rates per 1000 people" I am concerned that including the population as one of the control variables would result in multicollineraity between the population variable and the (rate) variables.

Comment: Could you give us more details on what exactly is your data and what are you predicting? Both relative (per 1000 inhabitants) or absolute values can make sense depending on your model.

Comment: Hi, first thanks for the reply, My data includes a range of different measures which have been collected by the governement (covering: Local authority spending, benefits spending, uneployment, local gross value added (similar to GDP), education, number of county court judements etc...).

Comment: I am trying to use this dataset to determine if a causal relationship may exist between cuts in benefits/government spending and the number of county court judements. I have chosen to use relative data because the counties (local authorities) all have very different populations.